# Ruby array five_sort algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm

I'm trying to solve a problem called five_sort that accepts an array of integers as the argument and places all the fives at the end of the array and leaves all of the other numbers unsorted. For example, `[1,2,5,3,2,5,5,7]` would be sorted as `[1,2,3,2,7,5,5,5]`.The rules for the problem state that only a while loops can be used and no other methods can be called on the array except `[]` and `[]=`. Here is my current code:

```
def five_sort(array)
    sorted = false
    while sorted == false
    idx = 0

      while idx < array.length
        if array[idx] == 5
            array[idx], array[idx + 1] = array[idx + 1], array[idx]
        end
        idx += 1
      end
    sorted = true
    end
array
end
```

When running it, it is just in a continuous loop but I can't find out how to fix it. I know that if I just run the second while loop without the `while sorted` loop, the array would only run once and the fives would only switch places once and the loop would be over. But I don't know how to run the second while loop and stop it once all the fives are at the end.

Can anyone help me figure this one out?

Comment: Not sure if you'd like a solution, or just a hint to point you in the right direction? As a hint, the list is correctly sorted when you make a pass through the list and there are no more swaps to make. So in the inner `while` loop try keeping track of if you've made any swaps and use this to decide whether to set `sorted` to true.

Comment: I don't know. Does the algorithm look mostly correct? Is it a small change I need or is my algorithm fundamentally wrong? If it's just a small change, what could I use to keep track of a swap? Like a `swap = 0` counter and then increment?

Comment: It's pretty close and just needs a couple of small changes. You're _always_ setting `sorted` to true after the first time round the second loop. So the loop only runs once. You've correctly worked out that you want the second loop to repeat until the list has all the 5's at the end. Hint is that the list is sorted when you go all the way through the second loop with nothing needing swapping. Notice that if `array[idx]` is a 5 and `array[idx+1]` is also 5 you aren't really swapping anything. Also, be careful not not to access array[idx+1] when idx is at the end of the array. Does that help?

Comment: Don't those rules forbid you using `array.length`?

Comment: Good spot @StefanPochmann - I hadn't picked up on that.

Comment: Consider what happens when `idx` points to the last element in the array, and that element is a `5`. You swap it with the next element, but what's the next element?

Comment: Oh yeah youre right @StefanPochmann. I totally missed that!

Answer (score 3):

Just a simple O(n) time and O(1) space solution, using a write-index and a read-index.

```
  w = r = 0
  while array[w]
    r += 1 while array[r] == 5
    array[w] = array[r] || 5
    w += 1
    r += 1
  end
```

Comment: RW-indices, of course! Very elegant, thank you. When I see code like this I always wonder what am I indeed using instead of brains for my whole life? :)

Comment: Nice one, Stefan!

Answer (score 1):

While a couple of people have posted alternative approaches, which are all good, I wanted to post something based on your own code to reassure you that you had got pretty close to a solution.

I've added comments to explain the changes I've made:

```
def five_sort(array)
  sorted = false
  while sorted == false
    idx = 0
    # use did_swap to keep track of if we've needed to swap any numbers
    did_swap = false

    # check if next element is nil as alternative to using Array#length
    while array[idx + 1] != nil
      # it's only really a swap if the other entry is not also a 5
      if array[idx] == 5 and array[idx + 1] != 5
        array[idx], array[idx + 1] = array[idx + 1], array[idx]
        did_swap = true
      end
      idx += 1
    end

    # if we've been through the array without needing to make any swaps
    # then the list is sorted
    if !did_swap
      sorted = true
    end
  end
  array
end
```

Comment: Thank you! I get so used to using the `length` method that I've neglected to think about how else I could stop at the end of an array. So not being able to use any methods on the array severely limited my problem solving.

It's an easy problem without the limitations placed on the solution. But I know the point of the problem is to get me thinking about logic rather than just manipulating objects.

Answer (score 0):

Your array is becoming longer at each loop:

```
array = [1,2]
array[1], array[2] = array[2], array[1]
puts array.length
```

Outputs 3.

What you need is to not swap if `idx = array.length - 1`

```
if (array[idx] == 5)
  array[idx], array[idx+1] = array[idx+1], array[idx] if idx != array.length - 1
end
```

Comment: `length` is a method of `Array` that is neither `[]` nor `[]=`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def five_sort(arr)
  i = 0
  cnt = 0
  while arr[i]
    if arr[i] == 5 && arr[i+1]         
      arr[i..i] = []
      cnt += 1                  
    else
      i += 1                    
    end
  end
  cnt.times { arr[-1,2] = [arr[-1],5] }
  arr 
end

arr = [1,5,3,5,6] 
five_sort arr
  #=> [1, 3, 6, 5, 5]
arr
  #=> [1, 3, 6, 5, 5] # confirms arr is mutated

five_sort [5,5,5,3,6]
  #=> [3, 6, 5, 5, 5]
five_sort [5,5,5,5,5]
  #=> [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
five_sort [1,2,3,4,6]
  #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 6]
five_sort []
  #=> []
```

Notes:

- As required by the spec, the only methods invoked on `arr` are `[]` and `[]=` and no other arrays are created.
- if `i` indexes the last element of the array, `arr[i+1]` equals `nil`.
- `arr[i..i] = []` removes the element`arr[i]` from `arr`.
- `arr[-1,2] = [arr[-1],5]` appends a `5` to `arr`.

Comment: I like this solution which I would have done, but I forgot to mention that the problem also forbids new arrays from being created.

Comment: I revised my answer to avoid the use of additional arrays.

Comment: (Read the question only after seeing you suggest `&& arr[i+1]`…)